# EditText scroll to last text line

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext, focus

So I have an `EditText` with fixed size that is most likely to contain a long text with multiple lines.

When the `view` doesn't have focus I want to scroll to the top of it. Managed to do that using `view.scrollBy(0,0)` inside it's `setOnFocusChangeListener` when `hasFocus` is `false`.

But I also want to scroll down to the last line of the `EditText` when `hasFocus` is `true`. Is there a way to get some valid `int` values to pass in the `view.scrollBy(x,y)` based on the last text line inside the `view`?

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: Yes, it worked out great. Thank you.

Comment: So I would be grateful if you accept my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `EditText` has focus then you could go with

```
editText.setSelection(editText.text.length) //place the cursor at the end of the text
```

which should automatically scroll down to the end of the `editText`

Check it out if it will work

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText);
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Comment: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />